# The different between association belongs_to and add field id when define a schema?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

What is the different when declare a relationship ?

```
schema "messages" do
    field :user_id, :id
end
```

and

```
schema "messages" do
    belongs_to :user, User
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `field :user_id, :id`, you're not actually declaring a relationship.  You're just adding  field called `user_id` with the type `id`.

`Belongs_to` actually adds the relationship, with the default assumption that the foreign key is `user_id`.  (This can be changed via the `foreign_key` opt).
By using belongs_to, Ecto knows how to handle the related record when doing things like preloading, how to create/update with a related User attached, how to cascade the delete, etc.